# Live Chat and WCAG 2.1

Tags: accessibility, wcag, wcag2.0

We are developing a live chat and wanting some clarification on whether we will meet WCAG 2.1.

Specifically we want to know if the way we handle the messages being received meets compliance.

If the agent responds to the user and the message window is updated, will an audible sound be a sufficient way to alert a screen reader user that a message has appeared?

So the story would be:

1. user types a question.
2. agent responds
3. an audible PING
4. user uses arrow keys to move up through the chat window to hear what the agent has written.

Would this meet WCAG 2.1?

Comment: You need to think about braille displays, using a "ping" isn't enough you need to announce with an `aria-live` region otherwise people using a braille display will not be able to use the site. What you haven't mentioned is has this user left the chat window (as you mention using arrow keys to move up and see what the agent has written which is confusing) or are they still within the chat window?

Comment: Thanks you @GrahamRitchie. I was thinking we should be using a live region. Sorry how do braille displays work?

Comment: Sorry they are in the chat window and waiting for a message. moving up would allow the user to find the message that has appeared.

Comment: Some excellent info here: https://accessibility.blog.gov.uk/2016/12/09/patterns-for-accessible-webchats/

Comment: So a braille display outputs the screen reader info but in braille. As long as everything gets announced correctly you don't have to worry too much about them (they do have a couple of idiosyncrasies but without one to test on it is hard to know these). So if your chat window outputs 'new message' that would get converted to braille on the braille display, it just can't do sounds.